# AntMatchers needed in a SinglePage Application using AngularJS and Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Single Page application Client side utilises AngularJS whereas Server side utilises Spring MVC, REST, Spring Data .When the app is deployed spring mvc renders a JSP page that has angular JS tags for multiple named ui-view corresponding to the various sections of the page as header , footer, menu and main content area.

Dispatcher servlet has the url mapping as /ui*. My only spring MVC controller renders itself to home.jsp. home.jsp has the multiple named angularJS ui-view tags as mentioned below . Routes are defined as in controller.js . web.xml is as shown below . There are innumerable REST API for CRUD operations using Spring data mongodb.

I want to secure this application using Spring security with Java configurations.

I am trying the code as below in my SecurityConfiguration.java file to allow login page to be rendered without authentication & other pages has to be authenticated.before access from the browser. Login page should be the only point of entry to the application. However this code is not working.
Please advise.

**NOTE** :- This is a Single page application. App has only one SpringMVC controller & it renders the singleJSP in application Home.jsp.Post deployment when we access the url  (http://localhost:8080/root/ui/login)
based on the route configured in the angularJS app the url changes to use fragmentidentifier as the url (http://localhost:8080/root/ui/login#/login)
that renders the Login page.
On click of any other hyperlink only the fragment identifier changes and makes a REST call to DB and populates the data for that particular section of the page. For Ex :- on click of chDetail hyperlink the url is changed as below (http://localhost:8080/root/ui/login#/chDetail) and it loads the data for that section.  Please advise how to write appropriate antMatchers so that
Login page can be accessed unsecuredly whereas other pages need to be authenticated for its access.

Security config code is as below :- (Please advise with the code here)

```
<code>
http.csrf().disable().httpBasic()
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/ui/login#/login").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/ui/login#/chDetail").authenticated();
</code>
```

Code snippet of other layers of the app is as below for reference.
Home.jsp code is as below.

```
 <code>
  <body ng-app="bpApp" ui-view>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="applicationPagelayout.html">
  <div class="grandContainer">  
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div class="menuSecCT">
            <div ui-view="userStatus"></div>
            <div ui-view="menu"></div>
    </div>      
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>      
    <p ui-view="footer"></p> 
</div>
</script>
</body>
</code>
```

Routing controller code is as below.

```
<code>
 bpApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider.state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract:true,  
   views: {      
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'applicationPagelayout.html'
        },

        'footer@root': {
            templateUrl:'resources/html/footer.html'
        },
        'header@root': {
            templateUrl:'resources/html/header.html'
        },
        'userStatus@root': {
        templateUrl:'resources/html/userStatus.html'
        },
        'menu@root': {
            templateUrl:'resources/html/menu.html'
        }               
    }

}).state('root.chDetail', {
     url: "/chDetail",
     views:{
          'content': {
     templateUrl: "resources/html/chDetail.html",
     controller: 'chDetailCtrl'
          }
     }
 }).state('login', { 
     url: "/login",
     controller: 'loginCtrl',
     templateUrl: "resources/html/login.html"
 });
 }]);

</code>
```

web.xml is as below that defines the url pattern for cxfservlet for REST and 
Dispatcher servlet for UI.

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Only springmvc controller in the project is

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/login")
 public class ChController {

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getListingPage() {
      return "HomePage";
 }
 }
```

Additionally lots of RESTFUL API's which use Apache-cxf . Spring data Mongo-db is used for CRUD on mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add something like this to your configuration chain.

```
 http.httpBasic()
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/root/ui/**").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: I have a login.html which is at the url pattern as localhost:8080/root/ui/login or localhost:8080/root/ui/login/#login . All other app pages are at url as below localhost:8080/root/ui/login#<<appPageUrl>> . Hence if I provide /root/ui** which is applicable for all the urls. Hence its all accessible or none.